# How to download sp.runtime.js file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to download sp.runtime.js file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can get `sp.runtime.js` from the below sharepoint online link.

https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.7514.1207/sp.runtime.js

I got this link by

1. opening dev tools in Chrome   navigating to network tab
2. open one of my SharePoint online sites
3. searched for `sp.runtime.js` from the network tab
4. get the link address of the js file loaded in the tab

You can use the same approach for getting all basic scripts from SharePoint Online. Works the same way in enterprise edition too assuming the js file is loaded in the page you are browsing.

Comment: Also most of the js files have a <name>.debug.js version, which is usually easier to read.

Comment: I thought the debug version had different compatibilities.. is the difference between dug and original version only readability..? @Rothrock

Comment: As far as I know that is the only difference. It is the unminified original layout with better argument names etc.

Comment: that's good to hear. I can learn about those basic js files more easily now. Thank you @Rothrock